# Two custom SXA renderings with variants conflict?

Tags: sxa

I created a first custom rendering for SXA with variant as [described in the docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/build-a-rendering-that-includes-variants.html) with a repository that inherits from `VariantsRepository` and it seems to work fine (we created one variant and that worked as expected).

I had to create another rendering that was rather similar - it belonged in the same feature, even in the same controller. So I created a new action method and placed a new GetModel function in my repository. Created the rendering in Sitecore, added a variant and all seemed fine.

But.. when I go to a page that has rendering B and then to a page with rendering A they seem to be interacting. Same thing happens the other way round. The first visited rendering seems to affect the second one as if caching is involved.

- I checked all caching settings. There are none.
- I added a breakpoint in both methods in my controller and both are called.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further debugging showed me that the `VariantsRepository` from SXA inherits from a `AbstractVariantsRepository` and that one holds the `variantItem` and `variantFields` as an instance variable in the repository. Those get filled when you call `FillBaseProperties`, but only if they are not already filled.

So my own repository (based upon the VariantsRepository) also has those properties. But I was using DI and as I usually don't put properties in my repositories so I marked my repository to be a *singleton*.

This caused the repository to read the variants item and fields for the first called rendering and keep those for all next calls. Creating a separate repository for the second rendering would not fix this - I had to remove the Singleton setting and replace that by Transient.

**Lesson learned**: when using DI, always add the *VariantsRepository* based repositories as *Transient* so they are created each time. This way the variant data is correctly filled by the FillBaseProperties method.

You could also override the `VariantItem` and `VariantFields` property getters without the null checks but that does not sound like the best idea.